# React not responsing to passed parameter variable

Tags: reactjs, jsx

React is not interact with passed parameter despite of it gives right result with static values in bellow code

```
<Voteresult res={4} color="blue" />
```

export const Voteresult = (props) => {
return <div className={`bg-${props.color}-600 m-0 p-0 h-fullw-${props.res}/5`}>
{console.log(`res is  ${props.res}`)}
{console.log(`color is  ${props.color}`)}

***remarks***

1. it printing expected value in console log as expected
2. if it given static value output is shown - for example  4/5  or bg-red-600

Answer (score 0):

```
export const Voteresult = (props) => { 
    return
    <div className={bg-${props.color}-600 m-0 p-0 h-full 
    w-${props.res}/5}> 

       {console.log(res is  ${props.res})} 
       {console.log(color is  ${props.color})}

    </div>
```

this is the code

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score 0):

`` export const Voteresult = (props) => { return <div className={`bg-${props.color}-600 m-0 p-0 h-fullw-${props.res}/5`}> ``

try this i think you are missing backticks while using type literal

Comment: I found the problem:  it must sent completely as 'res='w-8/12' not only variable

Answer (score 0):

From the code, it looks like you are trying to breakdown one tailwind class into multiple part to make it dynamic

Unfortunately, Tailwind requires the color to be hardcoded into the className prop as it cannot compute arbitrary styles from dynamic className values.

For above, you might need to define some predefined theme styles and use those enum to manage theme of the component.